# Can't deploy react app to google app engine

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWiKn.png) is the error I'm getting when trying to deploy my fresh started react app (It runs well locally). And this is my app.yaml file.

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reactJS apps are managed as static websites by app engine as React runs on the front-end.

Therefore you would need to configure the app.yaml to use static files.

For this you would need to add the handlers for static files.

```
handlers:
  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: favicon.ico

  - url: /static
    static_dir: public
```

If you need more guidance [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/serving-static-files#serving_from_your_application) is the official documentation for static files in App Engine.